# react: the DOM loading is too fast, leaving no time to load the items from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to the community, however I am French speaking, if the understanding of English is not correct, it's because I am using a translator.

I am busy redesigning a website, however, it was originally hardcoded all in html, javascript and jquery.

I convert it with React 17.0.x

however, I have a rendering problem on one of the pages, it is a photo gallery page.
there are buttons which allow to select the category of image, then the images of this categorie is displayed below with a display of grid

When I code it hard, the grid of the images displays correctly, but when I do call the images from the API, the images show one under the other and the buttons do not work. I have to press the F5 key several times simultaneously so that all the images are displayed correctly and that the buttons work.

**Original (hard coding) in de "render" of page/gallerie.js:**

```
    <section id="gallery" class="gallery-area section-padding">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="section-title">
                        <h5>Delicious Food Gallery</h5>
                        <h2>Resturant Gallery</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="gallery-list">
                        <ul class="nav" id="gallery-flters">
                            <li class="filter filter-active" data-filter=".all">all</li>
                            <li class="filter" data-filter=".breakfast">Break Fast</li>
                            <li class="filter" data-filter=".lunch">Lunch</li>
                            <li class="filter" data-filter=".dinner">Dinner</li>
                            <li class="filter" data-filter=".dessert">Dessert</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="gallery-container">
                    <!-- gallery-item -->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 gallery-grid-item all lunch dessert">
                        <div class="gallery-item">
                            <img src="assets/img/gallery/gallery-1.jpg" alt="image">
                            <div class="gallery-img-overlay">
                                <div class="gallery-content">
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <h6>Break Fast</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="assets/img/gallery/gallery-1.jpg" class="popimg">  <span class="icon"><i class="icofont-picture"></i></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- gallery-item -->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 gallery-grid-item all dinner breakfast">
                        <div class="gallery-item">
                            <img src="assets/img/gallery/gallery-2.jpg" alt="image">
                            <div class="gallery-img-overlay">
                                <div class="gallery-content">
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <h6>Lunch</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="assets/img/gallery/gallery-2.jpg" class="popimg">  <span class="icon"><i class="icofont-picture"></i></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- gallery-item -->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 gallery-grid-item all lunch dessert">
                        <div class="gallery-item">
                            <img src="assets/img/gallery/gallery-3.jpg" alt="image">
                            <div class="gallery-img-overlay">
                                <div class="gallery-content">
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <h6>Dinner</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="assets/img/gallery/gallery-3.jpg" class="popimg">  <span class="icon"><i class="icofont-picture"></i></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- gallery-item -->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 gallery-grid-item all lunch webdesig breakfastn">
                        <div class="gallery-item">
                            <img src="assets/img/gallery/gallery-4.jpg" alt="image">
                            <div class="gallery-img-overlay">
                                <div class="gallery-content">
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <h6>Dessert</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="assets/img/gallery/gallery-4.jpg" class="popimg">  <span class="icon"><i class="icofont-picture"></i></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- gallery-item -->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 gallery-grid-item all dinner dessert breakfast">
                        <div class="gallery-item">
                            <img src="assets/img/gallery/gallery-5.jpg" alt="image">
                            <div class="gallery-img-overlay">
                                <div class="gallery-content">
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <h6>Break Fast</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="assets/img/gallery/gallery-5.jpg" class="popimg">  <span class="icon"><i class="icofont-picture"></i></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- gallery-item -->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 gallery-grid-item all dinner dessert breakfast">
                        <div class="gallery-item">
                            <img src="assets/img/gallery/gallery-6.jpg" alt="image">
                            <div class="gallery-img-overlay">
                                <div class="gallery-content">
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <h6>Lunch</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="assets/img/gallery/gallery-6.jpg" class="popimg">  <span class="icon"><i class="icofont-picture"></i></span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**Main.js, functional script for isotope and MagnificPopup**

```
    
    // MagnificPopup 
    $('.gallery-container').magnificPopup({
        delegate: '.popimg',
        type: 'image',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        }
    });
    
    // Porfolio isotope and filter
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        var galleryIsotope = $('.gallery-container').isotope({
            itemSelector: '.gallery-grid-item'
        });
        $('#gallery-flters li').on('click', function () {
            $("#gallery-flters li").removeClass('filter-active');
            $(this).addClass('filter-active');
            galleryIsotope.isotope({
                filter: $(this).data('filter')
            });
        });
    });
```

[Here the display is correct in hard coding, the filter buttons work correctly (See this screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiiS7.jpg)

**version modify for react**

**File - > "page/Restaurant.js" :**

```
import React from "react";
import { HeaderCarousel, Gallery, Sponsoring } from 'components';

class Restaurant extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            galleryObj: [],
            gallerydescObj : [],
            galleryListObj : []
        };
      }
    componentDidMount() {
        
       const API_URL  = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
       const promises = Promise.all([
            fetch(API_URL + 'gallery'),
            fetch(API_URL + 'gallerydesc'),
            fetch(API_URL + 'listgallery')
        ]);
    
        promises
          .then((results) => 
            Promise.all( results.map(r => r.json()) )
          )
          .then( ([dataGallery, dataGallerydesc, dataGalleryList, ]) => {
              this.setState({
                galleryObj: dataGallery,
                gallerydescObj: dataGallerydesc,
                galleryListObj: dataGalleryList

            })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          });
          

      }

  render() {



      return (
        <div  className="galerie">

                    <HeaderCarousel /> 
  
                    <Gallery 
                        descs=      { this.state.gallerydescObj }
                        items=      { this.state.galleryObj }
                        filters=    { this.state.galleryListObj }
                    />

                    <Sponsoring /> 

        </div>          
      );
    }
}

export default Restaurant;
```

**File - > "component/Gallery.js" :**

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import {Filter} from "./Filter";
import { Images, Filter} from "./index";

class Gallery extends React.Component {

  render() {

    const descs = this.props.descs;

    const title = descs.map(function(desc, index){

            return  <div key={index} className="section-title">
                      <h5>{ desc.introdesc }</h5>
                      <h2>{ desc.titledesc }</h2>
                    </div>
          })

    return ( <section id="gallery" className="gallery-area section-padding">
                <Container>
                  <Row>
                    <Col lg="12" md="12">
                      {title}
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Col md="12">
                      <Filter filters = {this.props.filters} />
                    </Col>
                      <Images galleries = {this.props.items} />
                  </Row>
                </Container>
              </section>
      
    );
  }
}

export default Gallery;
```

**File - > "component/index.js" :**

```
export { default as Filter } from './Filter';
export { default as Image } from './Image';
```

**File - > "component/Filter.js" :**

```
import React from "react";

class Filter extends React.Component {


  render() {

    const filters = this.props.filters;


     const catFilter = filters.map(function(cat, index){

      const nameLowerCase = cat.name.toLowerCase();
      const nameFilter = "."+ nameLowerCase;
      
      return  <li key={index} className="filter" data-filter={nameFilter}>
                {nameLowerCase}
              </li>
      })      

    return ( <div className="gallery-list">
                <ul className="nav" id="gallery-flters">
                    <li className="filter filter-active" data-filter=".all">all</li>
                    {catFilter}
                </ul>
            </div>
      
    );
  }
}

export default Filter;
```

**File - > "component/Images.js" :**

```
import React from "react";
import imageUrl from 'constants/imageUrl';
import { Col } from 'reactstrap';

class Image extends React.Component {

  render() {

    const galleries = this.props.galleries;
 
    const medias = galleries.map(function(item){

        const name = item.name.toLowerCase();
        const image = item.Medias.map(function(media){ return media });

        const imgs = image.map(function(img, index){
        
          const classCat  = 'gallery-grid-item all ' + name; 
          const imageURL  = imageUrl.Galerie + img.image;
  
          return  <Col lg="4" md="6" key={index}  className={classCat}>
                    <div className="gallery-item">
                    <img src={imageURL} alt={img.alt} />
                        <div className="gallery-img-overlay">
                          <div className="gallery-content">
                            <div className="info">
                              <h6>{name}</h6>
                            </div>
                            <a href={imageURL} className="popimg">  
                              <span className="icon">
                                <i className="icofont-picture" />
                              </span>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </Col>
        })
            return imgs;
       });    

    return (  <div className="gallery-container">
                  {medias}
                </div>
      
    );
  }
}

export default Image;
```

**fetch(API_URL + 'listgallery') :**``

```
[
    {
        "name": "Break"
    },
    {
        "name": "Lunch"
    },
    {
        "name": "Dinner"
    },
    {
        "name": "Dessert"
    }
]
```

**fetch(API_URL + 'gallery') :**``

```
[
    {
        "name": "Break",
        "Medias": [
            {
                "image": "gallery-2.jpg",
                "alt": "gallery-2",
                "gallerie_as_media": {
                    "galleryId": 1,
                    "mediaId": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "image": "gallery-4.jpg",
                "alt": "gallery-4",
                "gallerie_as_media": {
                    "galleryId": 1,
                    "mediaId": 4
                }
            },
            {
                "image": "gallery-5.jpg",
                "alt": "gallery-5",
                "gallerie_as_media": {
                    "galleryId": 1,
                    "mediaId": 5
                }
            },
            {
                "image": "gallery-6.jpg",
                "alt": "gallery-6",
                "gallerie_as_media": {
                    "galleryId": 1,
                    "mediaId": 6
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Lunch",
        "Medias": [
            {
                "image": "gallery-1.jpg",
                "alt": "gallery-1",
                "gallerie_as_media": {
                    "galleryId": 2,
                    "mediaId": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "image": "gallery-3.jpg",
                "alt": "gallery-3",
                "gallerie_as_media": {
                    "galleryId": 2,
                    "mediaId": 3
                }
            },
            {
                "image": "gallery-4.jpg",
                "alt": "gallery-4",
                "gallerie_as_media": {
                    "galleryId": 2,
                    "mediaId": 4
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Dinner",
        "Medias": [
            {
                "image": "gallery-2.jpg",
                "alt": "gallery-2",
                "gallerie_as_media": {
                    "galleryId": 3,
                    "mediaId": 2
                }
            },
            {
                "image": "gallery-5.jpg",
                "alt": "gallery-5",
                "gallerie_as_media": {
                    "galleryId": 3,
                    "mediaId": 5
                }
            },
            {
                "image": "gallery-6.jpg",
                "alt": "gallery-6",
                "gallerie_as_media": {
                    "galleryId": 3,
                    "mediaId": 6
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Dessert",
        "Medias": [
            {
                "image": "gallery-1.jpg",
                "alt": "gallery-1",
                "gallerie_as_media": {
                    "galleryId": 4,
                    "mediaId": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "image": "gallery-3.jpg",
                "alt": "gallery-3",
                "gallerie_as_media": {
                    "galleryId": 4,
                    "mediaId": 3
                }
            },
            {
                "image": "gallery-4.jpg",
                "alt": "gallery-4",
                "gallerie_as_media": {
                    "galleryId": 4,
                    "mediaId": 4
                }
            },
            {
                "image": "gallery-5.jpg",
                "alt": "gallery-5",
                "gallerie_as_media": {
                    "galleryId": 4,
                    "mediaId": 5
                }
            },
            {
                "image": "gallery-6.jpg",
                "alt": "gallery-6",
                "gallerie_as_media": {
                    "galleryId": 4,
                    "mediaId": 6
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

[Incorrect display and buttons do not work, forced to press F5 several times to force display correctly (See this screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx9Yd.jpg)

There must be something wrong with the display, I think the DOM loads too empty before the API responds, or the API mapping is wrong.
I am not an expert in React, I only started for 1 month on React.

If you can help me solve this problem?

I searched for several days on Google, stackoverflow, Github but I can not find anything as a clue.

On the other hand, the version of magnific-popup and isotope.pkgd.min.js seem not to exist for the last version of React, I put them in "assets / js"

But I don't think it's isotope and magnific-popup that are responsible for the bad display and the filter malfunction and galerie, because when the gallery and the filters are hard-coded with react, they work without having to simultaneously press F5 several times.

Thank you for your help.

Best Regards !

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve] (__minimal!__), and be included in your question.

Comment: Please remember that SO is not for asking people to fix your entire project, it's for asking help on fixing a single, specific problem, which means you're responsible for reducing your code to show off that problem, and nothing else. Remove everything from your code that isn't related to the problem by actually spending time on creating a [mcve]. Not just for "us" here on Stackoverflow, but also because forcing yourself to create a true MCVE almost always ends up with you discovering what's going on all on your own.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).